# HTMX websockets extension doesn't connect to Django channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, channel, htmx

I try to connect a Django channels Consumer to a HTMX `ext-ws` element, but I can't get a step further.

```py
class MessageConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
        print("connect")
        #self.send( 
        #    "type": "websocket.send",
        #    "text": "..."
        #)
```

```html
...
<head>
...
  <script src="{% static 'common/js/htmx/htmx.min.js' %}" defer></script>
  <script src="{% static 'common/js/htmx/ext/ws.js' %}" defer></script>
...
</head>
...
```

The HTMX.js and the ws.js gets loaded correctly at the client's browser.

```
<div id="messages-container"
     hx-ws="connect:/ws/messages/" 
  {# hx-ext="ws" ws-connect="/ws/messages/" does not work at all #}
    
>
  <div id="message"></div>
</div>
```

If I use the old HTMX-builtin `hx-ws` method, at least the websocket connects. But I can't get a message to the  HTMX element (I thought the `#message` div should be replaced).

If I use the new-style (HTMX extension) syntax (`hx-ext="ws" ws-connect...`)

Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per docs you need to also include `hx-swap-oob="true"` attribute into the html that you send back from websocket:

See example from htmx GH:
https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/blob/master/test/servers/ws/server.go#L24

When using the plugin version, what worked for me was removing the defer attribute from htmx related script tags.
Not sure why including defer is causing the issue though.

**Update:**

A GH issue has been opened by OP:
https://github.com/bigskysoftware/htmx/issues/957

Comment: Yes, I know, but that was not my question. The lines there are demo code. The problem is that it doesn't **connect**. Sending data is one step after that. In the code above, it should at least print ("connect") to the server's stdout. I'll remove that <div> to make it clearer. I also updated the title, maybe it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @nerdoc Thanks for clearing it up for me. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Whoa! Definitely. I removed the "defer" and everything worked! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Maybe you could point that out in the answer a bit more? I opened a bug at HTMX' to to tell them - because this smells like a bug to me...